# Very Simple Regex Question

Tags: java, regex

I have a very simple regex question. Suppose I have 2 conditions:

1. url =http://www.abc.com/cde/def
2. url =https://www.abc.com/sadfl/dsaf

How can I extract the baseUrl using regex?

Sample output:

1. http://www.abc.com
2. https://www.abc.com

Comment: this looks just like homework

Comment: @Gyom This looks nothing like homework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
String baseUrl;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(([a-zA-Z]+://)?[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+(:\d+)?/");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
if (m.matches())
    baseUrl = m.group(1);
```

However, you should use the [`URI` class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) instead, like this:

```
URI uri = new URI(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response
but it gives 
https://www.abc.com
sadfl
can it is possible it only gives first one https://www.abc.com

Comment: This is not working with page source.suppose I am searching a string 'sun' on google it will give 20 link and I want to fetch all sites base url but this is not working on page source of html page.Any change so that It can work for page source. Thanks . waiting for response.

Comment: Remove the `^`, which anchors the regex to the beginning of the string.  You can then loop through each match.

Answer (score 2):

A one liner without regexp:

```
String baseUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', url.indexOf("//")+2));
```

Comment: :)
Thanks for your answer But I want using regex

Answer (score 1):

`/^(https?\:\/\/[^\/]+).*/$1/`

This will capture ANYTHING that starts with http and $1 will contain everything from the beginning to the first / after the //

Answer (score 1):

Except for write-and-throw-away scripts, you should *always* refrain from parsing complex syntaxes (e-mail addresses, urls, html pages, etc etc) using regexes.

believe me, you *will* get bitten eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there is a Java class that will allow path manipulations, but if it has to be a regex,

```
https?://[^/]+
```

would work. (`s?` included to also handle `https:`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the simplest solution to your two specific examples would be the pattern:

```
[^/]_//[^/]+
```

i.e.: non-slash (0 or more times), two slashes, non-slash (0 or more times).  You can be stricter than that if you wish, as the two existing answers are doing in different ways -- one will reject e.g. URLs starting with `ftp:`, the other will reject domains with underscores (but accept URLs without a leading `protocol://`, thereby being even broader than mine in that respect).  This variety of answers (all correct wrt your scant specs;-) should suggest to you that your specs are too vague and should be tightened.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that should satisfy the problem as given.

```
https?://[^/]*
```

I'm assuming you're asking this partly to gain more knowledge of regexes.  If, however, you're trying to pull the host from a URL, it's arguably much more correct to use Java's more robust parsing methods:

```
String urlStr = "https://www.abc.com/stuff";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
String host = url.getHost();
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
URL baseUrl = new URL (protocol, host);
```

This is better, as it should catch more cases if your input URL isn't as strict as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Old post.. thought I might as well put a simple answer to a simple regex Q:

`(http|https):\/\/(www.)?(\w+)?\.(\w+)?`