# Selenium: Find the base Url

Tags: c#, url, selenium

I'm using Selenium on different machines to automate testing of a MVC Web application.

My problem is that I can't get the base url for each machine.

I can get the current url using the following code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
string currentUrl = driver.Url;
```

But this doesn't help when I need to navigate to a different page.

Ideally I could just use the following to navigate to different pages:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl+ "/Feedback");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl+ "/Home");
```

A possible workaround I was using is:

```
string baseUrl = currentUrl.Remove(22); //remove everything from the current url but the base url
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl+ "/Feedback");
```

Is there a better way I could do this??

Comment: Just to make sure I follow this. Example: Given `http://www.google.com/something` ...and you want *specifically* just the `http://www.google.com` part?

Comment: When I run the application it will go to a url such as http://localhost:12345/Login (this will be different depending on the machine), I then want the driver to go to page such as http://localhost:12345/Feedback. So I just want the http://localhost:12345/ part as I can't hardcode a link to it in my code since it will different on every machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way around this would be to create a `Uri` instance of the URL.

This is because the `Uri` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri.aspx) in .NET already has code in place to do this exactly for you, so you should just use that. I'd go for something like (untested code):

```
string url = driver.Url; // get the current URL (full)
Uri currentUri = new Uri(url); // create a Uri instance of it
string baseUrl = currentUri.Authority; // just get the "base" bit of the URL
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl + "/Feedback");
```

Essentially, you are after the [Authority property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx) within the `Uri` class.

Note, there is a property that does a similar thing, called [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) but this does not include port numbers, which your site does. It's something to bear in mind though.

Answer (score 2):

Take the `driver.Url`, toss it into a new `System.Uri`, and use `myUri.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority)`.

If your base URL is `http://localhost:12345/Login`, this will return you `http://localhost:12345`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998233/very-simple-regex-question).

```
String baseUrl;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(([a-zA-Z]+://)?[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+(:\d+)?/");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
if (m.matches())
    baseUrl = m.group(1);
```