# How to get the URL of the current window using Selenium WebDriver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application when sign-in, then it navigates to another page. Now I need to get that new URL using WebDriver in selenium C#.

I can't find any function to do this. I have tried `driver.Url`, 
`driver.getLocation()` and `driver.getCurrentUrl()`, but nothing is working in my C# application. So is it possible get the current URL somehow? After it gets navigated?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, you can get the URL of the current page. Instantiate your driver and then get the driver's **Url** property.

**Code snippet:**

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String currentURL =  driver.Url;
```

**Help from:**
[Selenium: Find the base Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465290/selenium-find-the-base-url)

Comment: This doesn't allways work. If you explicitly go to a url with Navigate().goToUrl(...), then it will work. But if you f.ex. click on a link that takes you to another url, calling driver.Url again will give you the old url and not the current one.

Comment: @FrankH. That's not technically true. `Driver.Url` returns the current browser URL. It sounds like you may need to wait for the new page to load before returning the URL. It depends on the site and how fast pages transition.

Comment: This is an easy and good method, but you should wait for the page to load or to navigate successfully, otherwise, you will get an old URL or nothing.

Comment: @FrankH. noticing the same behavior still, any workaround?

Comment: if selenium opens a new tab by clicking a javascript link this value never gets updated so this method doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver("C:\\");
Console.WriteLine("url "+ driver.Url);
```

*driver.Url gives you the current url*

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
String currentURL =  driver.getCurrentURL();
This will give you current URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods on this page don't work if tab is opened by javascript button.  In that case you need to do somethign like this:

```cs
wait.Until(wd => wd.WindowHandles.Count == 2);

var handles = _driver.WindowHandles;

_driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles.Last());

Console.WriteLine(_driver.Url);
```

Switching to the tab by getting all window handles sets the URL value